# What is the elementary methods?How we define elementary methods for integrals?And why we just can't solve these with elementary methods?

Tags: integration, soft-question

First of all, what is the elementary methods for solution of integrals?Who decides this?For example,[Evaluate $\int x^2e^{x^2} dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2213540/evaluate-int-x2ex2-dx)
and $\displaystyle\sqrt{lnx}dx$ or $\displaystyle\int e^{sin(e^x)}dx$

When I try to solve these integrals and fail,then want wolfram to solve these,and I always get this

$$\text{(no result found in terms of standard mathematical functions)}$$

What is the "standard mathematical function", Can  $\left[\dfrac2{\sqrt \pi}\displaystyle\int^x_0 e^{t^2}dt\right]$ be a standard function?Why not?

What is the tiny line between standard and non-standard functions?Why we can't  solve these non-elementary integrals with elementary methods?Can we define or fidn all elementary methods?

Comment: The term "elementary function" does have a meaning, and I find an expository paper [here](http://wstein.org/edu/winter06/20b/Conrad.pdf).